# Redirect directory to the same directory but in a subfolder using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Lets take the following example:

```
Redirect 301 /crowdfund/ http://website.com/crowdfund/browse/
```

Currently its creating a redirect in this format:

http://website.com/crowdfund/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/browse/

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` for exact regex match instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/crowdfund/?$ http://website.com/crowdfund/browse/
```

In your rule `/crowdfund/` is being matched before and after redirect.